# XML serialization in IE11

Tags: javascript, xml, serialization, internet-explorer-11

I am currently facing an issue with XML serialization in IE11. It is adding unwanted namespace. Worked in Chrome, but not in IE11.

```
this.xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet', 'Workbook', null);
this.xmlDoc.documentElement.setAttribute('xmlns:o', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office');
this.xmlDoc.documentElement.setAttribute('xmlns:x', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel');
this.xmlDoc.documentElement.setAttribute('xmlns:dt', 'uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882');
this.xmlDoc.documentElement.setAttribute('xmlns:s', 'uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882');
this.xmlDoc.documentElement.setAttribute('xmlns:rs', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset');
this.xmlDoc.documentElement.setAttribute('xmlns:z', '#RowsetSchema');
this.xmlDoc.documentElement.setAttribute('xmlns:ss', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet');
this.xmlDoc.documentElement.setAttribute('xmlns:html', 'http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40');
```

I cannot find any way to fix this. setAttributeNS doesn't work and gives me namespace error.